# How can I make Quick Play Start Working

Tags: team-fortress-2

Up until not long ago, I could go into the quick play section, hit the "play now" button, and I would get a server. Recently it has stopped working, saying there are no servers available. Yet I can find servers in the server browser, favorite etc.

Is there any fix for this? Could this have been caused by me installing a new HUD?

Comment: The same thing happened to me and both of my friends playing. I think it's systematic. I'm not sure it's working for anyone.

Comment: I haven't had much luck playing TF2 at all lately. Can't find any servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Valve Master Servers have been [having issues](http://forum.i3d.net/hlds-valve-linux-newsletter/181746-hlds_linux-master-server-issue.html) over the past couple of days.  It's a problem across a variety of games that use these servers.  Matchmaking and server browser issues are a symptom of these problems.  We just have to wait for them to fix it.

Comment: Great thanks i suspect it was something to do with the master server but i just wanted to confirm this hopeing that there was a fix =)